# How do I set a model field to the current count?

Tags: django, django-models

Say I have some groups with some items. I would like items to have a unique index within a group:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, null=True)
    index = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        unique_together=('group','index')

    def save(self):
        if self.pk is None and self.group_id is not None:
            self.thread_index = Item.objects.filter(group_id=group_id).count()+1
        return super(Item, self).save()
```

But this is problematic because the update is not atomic, i.e. another transaction may have added another row after I calculate thread_index and before I write to the database.

I understand that I can get it working with catching IntegrityError and retrying. But I wonder if there's a good way to populate it atomically as part of the insert command, with SQL something like:

```
insert into app_item (group, index) 
select 25, count(*) from app_item where group_id=25
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using django models, what does adding an index field give you over the [primary key](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields) added to all models unless you specify otherwise? Unless you need items to have sequential indices, which would still be problematic upon deleting objects, the id field would certainly appear to satisfy the requirement as you outlined it.

If you have to have this field, then an option could be to take advantage of [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/). Write a receiver for the object's post_save signal and it could conceivably handle it.

Comment: the index is per group, not global.

Comment: post_save is too late. I considered pre_save, but I believe it surfers from the same issue I'm trying to address

Comment: Why won't a global index work for you? If there really is a need for group-specific indices, it sounds like you have a use case for one sequence per group. Inserting a COUNT() won't work if you require uniqueness within the group and allow objects to be deleted or moved between groups.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution could be if you have issues with signals or custom save approach, calculate it at runtime by making `index` a [property field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#model-methods)

```
class Item(models.Model):
  group = models.ForeignKey(Group, null=True)

def _get_index(self):
  "Returns the index of groups"
   return Item.objects.filter(group_id=group_id).count()+1
index = property(_get_index)
```

Now use `index` as field of `Item` model.